# Creating long forms in FileMaker Pro

Tags: forms, filemaker

I am creating long forms in FileMaker Pro with many unique questions in each form.

Each unique question is comprised of: a radio button, two fields of support data, 4 container fields, and a field for comments. There is also a map feature that collects the device location when using an iPad.

Because each question is unique, I have been creating up to 8 fields for each question. The forms I am creating contain up to 40 questions.

Example fields:

Question1

Question1_Comments

Question1_Value1

Question1_Value2

Question1_Image[1], Question1_Image[2], Question1_Image[3], Question1_Image[4]

Is there is a simpler way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I can offer some general suggestions, but it sounds like you need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data. Whenever you start creating fields of the form `Field1`, `Field2`, etc., that's a hint that you should probably create a separate table. In your case it sounds like you need at least three tables:

- `Forms`
- `Questions`
- `Files`

This is going from the information you've provided that each form has many questions and each question has many files (container fields). Assuming that your form table already has a primary key field (a field that is unique for every record, often an auto-enter serial number), the Questions table would have the following fields:

- `id` (primary key)
- `form_id`
- `question`
- `comments`
- `value1`
- `value2`

Then the Files table would have two fields:

- `id`
- `question_id`
- `file`

Then you'd create a relationship from `Forms` to `Questions` with `Forms::id=Questions::form_id` and from `Questions` to `Files` with `Questions::id=Files::question_id`. If both of the value fields will always have data, I'd leave them in the `Questions` table, but if one of them could be blank, or if you think you may someday want more than two, I'd break that into it's own table as well.

Check the [FileMaker documentation](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/relational.11.12.html) for more information on creating relationships.